# Foregroud Notifications Not Showing in Capacitor 3 App using OneSignal

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal, capacitor

I have an Ionic 5.x app using Capacitor 3.2.3. We're using `onesignal-cordova-plugin` to send push notifications and register devices to receive push notifications.

We are able to receive notifications without any issues when the app is in the background. However, when the app is in the foreground I'm unable to receive notifications. I understand that using apps later then iOS 10 require the implementation of the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, but even when I have that implemented I'm still unable to receive notifications in the foreground.

I've implemented the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
     print("Push notification received in foreground.")
     completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
  }
```

But when I set a breakpoint this function is never called.

I'm not using any of the capacitor push notification packages.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.6",
    "@capacitor-community/apple-sign-in": "^1.0.1",
    "@capacitor-community/facebook-login": "^3.1.1",
    "@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics": "^1.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.2.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.2.3",
    "@capacitor/device": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.2.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.1.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.0",
    "@innomobile/capacitor-branch-deep-links": "^1.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.6.12",
    "@ionic/core": "^5.6.12",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "capacitor-rate-app": "^1.1.0",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^10.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^4.0.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "swiper": "^7.0.6",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Comment: Hi! Have you followed the migration guide to use the major release sdk: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/step-by-step-cordova-2x-to-300-upgrade-guide 

and our setup guide (which doesn't mention or use the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate): https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup

Then check the logs while the app is running and receive the notification for clues on if the message is being received or not.

Comment: @devpato Yes, I've been using version 3 for awhile. I followed all the migrations guides. This was working fine prior to me updating to Capacitor version 3. In order to get around this I'm using `setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler` within my Ionic app and when I receive a response in that command I'm scheduling a local notification, which is not ideal at all.